# malloc conditions for failure

Tags: c++, c, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I'm brushing up on c, redoing some old exercizes and getting some unusual results when I run this snippet (I know its leaking but want to find out how much the system allows..)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    void *page = 0; int index;
    index = 0;
    while(1)
    {
        page = malloc(1073741824); //1GB
        if(!page)break;
        ++index;
    }
    printf("memory failed at %d\n",index);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm actually getting:

> memory failed at 131070

this indicates it thinks its allocated 131070 x 1GB memory (leaking generously)

I had previously understood malloc should fail before consuming all virtual memory and certainly if I try and malloc 20GB in one block this fails.

My setup:
ubuntu 10
8Gb ram,
<= 2Gb swap,
HD 1TB (does this matter?)

anyone have an idea how it can leak more memory than I have

Comment: The answer here depends strongly on the OS you are using because some (notable linux) are willing to "over commit" meaning that malloc will return success if there is an *address* available without much concern about the availability of *memory*

Comment: Suggestion: you might want to instrument with mallinfo: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Statistics-of-Malloc.html

Comment: amd64, and ulimit does say max memory unlimited, however how can it over commit beyond even HD 1TB limits

Comment: Linux is an optimist that way. It's hoping that you'll be done with some of the memory you've requested it before you try to use other parts (and it consequently has to actually make them available).

Comment: I think the Firefox developers were trying this exact same test, but they forgot to comment it out in the release version....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- http://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/linux/lk/lk-9.html

> Since 2.1.27 there are a sysctl VM_OVERCOMMIT_MEMORY and proc file
>   /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory with values 1: do overcommit, and 0
>   (default): don't. Unfortunately, this does not allow you to tell the
>   kernel to be more careful, it only allows you to tell the kernel to be
>   less careful. With overcommit_memory set to 1 every malloc() will
>   succeed. When set to 0 the old heuristics are used, the kernel still
>   overcommits.
>   
>   You might also wish to look at instrumenting with mallinfo:

- http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Statistics-of-Malloc.html

One final link:

- http://opsmonkey.blogspot.com/2007/01/linux-memory-overcommit.html

> In a way, Linux allocates memory the way an airline sells plane
>   tickets. An airline will sell more tickets than they have actual
>   seats, in the hopes that some of the passengers don't show up. Memory
>   in Linux is managed in a similar way, but actually to a much more
>   serious degree.

Comment: That information is outdated. 1 means "do overcommit", but 0 does not mean "don't". 0 just means "avoid the most egregious cases of overcommit". There was a new option, 2, added much later which actually means "do not overcommit. at all."

Comment: And any properly configured system should have the sysctl set to 2.

Comment: Nope, 2 means obey the vm.overcommit_ratio sysctl: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/overcommit-accounting

Comment: @R.. Are you saying that the OOM-killer is *not your friend*? You're a meanie!

Comment: ok so my /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory is 0 though as mentioned its still free to overcommit, am now using mallinfo and can see arena and uordblks have both wrapped to -[large numbers]

Comment: in future should I always check for mallinfo feasibility after mallocing?  Ive never seen this in use..

Comment: @amdixon: That really depends on what king of tolerance you have for the consequences of running out of memory.

Comment: `mallinfo` is deprecated/unmaintained, and uses 32-bit int counters, so the interface is fundamentally broken on 64-bit machines...

Comment: @amdixon: The correct action is to simply check the return value of `malloc`. It's not your job to work around misconfigured systems. But you also shouldn't assume it's okay to allocate as much memory as you can. Instead allocate only what you *need*. Your program is (usually) not the only program running on the user's machine. If you only allocate what you need, it's unlikely your users will ever run into a situation where your program runs out of memory, unless some other program was misbehaving.

Comment: @R..: fair enough, these sizes are definitely unrealistic - but how would you go about configuring a linux system properly (so malloc fails when it should)?

Comment: `echo "2" > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory`